# What are the Negative energy and Positive energy spells

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

What are all the negative spells and positive spells?

I am reading all the spells one by one and it is proving quite time draining

Ps. I only need the name's list or a methodology to search them around the manuals.

Comment: <comments removed> If anyone has an issue with any version of this question, I suggest expressing on meta, it seems to me we've been splitting hair over nothing here. A few notes: reminder to flag redundant comments as NLN, helps against noise and misfires. If voting to close as unclear, it's very useful if you also express why (if not already commented). That seems to have been skipped here, to great confusion. Also if the problem is abundantly clear (which this was) and there's only a matter of unfortunate frame, you have an Edit button and not just a Close one :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are not really any *good* methodologies for searching *all* of the spells. For one thing, no central listing of all 3.5e spells exists. For another, most spells are legally found only in books, which means there is no electronic search. Finally, the spells do not have a clear, consistent format of indicating positive or negative energy.

That said, to the best of my knowledge, this list is as close to complete as currently exists:

#### Positive Energy

| Spell | Level | Description | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *aura of the sun* | Clr 4, Pal 4 | “Fills an area with light that damages undead and hampers magical darkness.” No healing. | *Lost Empires of Faerûn* |
| *bless water* | Clr 1, Hlr 1, Pal 1, knight of the chalice 1 | “Makes holy water.” No direct damage or healing. | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *bolt of glory* | Clr 6, Glory 6 | “Positive energy ray deals extra damage to evil outsiders and undead.” No healing. | *Spell Compendium** |
| *conduit of life* | Clr 2, Pal 2 | “Heal 2d10+1/caster level (max. 10) points of damage to yourself while channeling positive energy.” No damage to the undead. | *Complete Champion* |
| *consecrate* | Clr 2, Divine Brd 2, knight of the chalice 2, Celestial 2 | “Fills an area with positive energy, making undead weaker.” No healing or damage. | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *consecrate battlefield* | Clr 6 | “Fills large area with positive energy, making undead weaker.” No healing or damage. | *Heroes of Battle* |
| *cure critical wounds* | Clr 4, Dru 5, Urban Dru 5, Hlr 4, hunter of the dead 4, knight of the weave 4, Healing 4 | “Cures 4d8 damage +1/level (max +20).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure critical wounds, mass* | Clr 8, Dru 9, Urban Dru 9, Hlr 7, Healing 8 | “Cures 4d8 damage +1/level (max +40) for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure light wounds* | Brd 1, Clr 1, Dru 1, Urban Dru 1, Hlr 1, Pal 1, Rng 2, savant 1 (divine), adept 1, hunter of the dead 1, knight of the weave 1, Nentyar hunter 1, Healing 1 | “Cures 1d8 damage +1/level (max +5).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure light wounds, mass* | Brd 5, Clr 5, Dru 6, Urban Dru 6, Hlr 4, Elysium 5, Healing 5 | “Cures 1d8 damage +1/level (max +25) for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure minor wounds* | Divine Brd 0, Clr 0, Dru 0, Urban Dru 0, Hlr 0, adept 0 | “Cures 1 point of damage.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure moderate wounds* | Brd 2, Clr 2, Dru 3, Urban Dru 3, Hlr 2, Pal 2, Rng 2, adept 2, hunter of the dead 2, knight of the weave 2, Nentyar hunter 2, runescarred berserker 1, Healing 2 | “Cures 2d8 damage +1/level (max +10).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure moderate wounds, mass* | Brd 6, Clr 6, Dru 7, Urban Dru 7, Hlr 5 | “Cures 2d8 damage +1/level for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure serious wounds* | Brd 3, Clr 3, Dru 4, Urban Dru 4, Hlr 3, Pal 3, Rng 3, adept 3, hunter of the dead 3, knight of the weave 3, Nentyar hunter 3, runescarred berserker 2, Healing 3 | “Cures 3d8 damage +1/level (max +15).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *cure serious wounds, mass* | Clr 7, Dru 8, Urban Dru 8, Hlr 6 | “Cures 3d8 damage +1/level for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *darts of life* | Clr 5 | “Create ten projectiles that you can launch at allies to cure 1d8 points of damage each.” | *Complete Champion* |
| *death ward* | Clr 4, Dru 5, Urban Dru 5, Hlr 4, Pal 4, blighter 4, death delver 4, death master 4, dread necromancer 4, hunter of the dead 4, knight of the weave 4, slayer of Domiel 4, runescarred berserker 3, Death 4, Undeath 4 | “Grants immunity to death spells and negative energy effects.” Doesn’t explicitly state it’s positive energy, but everything it does counteracts negative energy, and its dual, *life ward*, is explicitly negative energy. | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *disrupt undead* | Dsk 0, Sha 0, Sor 0, Wiz 0, death master 0, warmage 0, wu jen 0, Glory 1 | “Deals 1d6 damage to one undead.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *embrace of the endless day* | Clr 4, Pal 3 | (No official short description?) Gives a subject a positive energy touch similar to lay on hands, and +1 to saves vs. necromancy or death. | *Faiths of Eberron* |
| *faith healing* | Clr 1, Pal 1, blackguard 1 | “Cures 8 hp +1/level (max +5) to worshiper of your deity.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *glory of the martyr* | Pal 4, champion of Gwynharwyf 4 | “As *shield other*, but with multiple targets.” No damage. | *Book of Exalted Deeds* |
| *glowing orb* | Clr 4, Sor 3, Wiz 3 | “Creates permanent magical light, you control brightness.” Just light, no damage or healing. | *Spell Compendium* |
| *glyph of turning* | Clr 3 | “As *glyph of warding*, except channeled positive or negative energy.” Stores turning or rebuking undead. | *Ghostwalk* |
| *grave strike* | Clr 1, Pal 1 | “You can sneak attack undead for 1 round.” No healing, no direct damage. | *Spell Compendium** |
| *hammer of righteousness* | Sanctified 3 | “Deals 1d6 points of damage per caster level, or 1d8 points of damage per caster level if the target is evil.” No healing. | *Book of Exalted Deeds* |
| *heal* | Clr 6, Dru 7, Urban Dru 7, Hlr 6, adept 5, runescarred berserker 5, Healing 6 | “Cures 10 points/level of damage, all diseases and mental conditions.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *healing circle* | Clr 5, Nentyar hunter 5 | “Allies can tap healing energy pool for *cure* spells.” No damage. | *Complete Champion* |
| *healing spirit* | Brd 4, Clr 4, Dru 4, Pal 3 | “Ball of light heals 1d8/round.” | *Player’s Handbook II* |
| *incarnum vigor* | Clr 6, Dru 7, Incarnum 6 | “Subject gains fast healing; his healing spells cure extra damage.” No damage. | *Magic of Incarnum* |
| *insignia of healing* | Brd 3, Clr 3 | “Bearers of special insignia healed of 1d8 damage +1 point/level (max. +10).” | *Races of Destiny* |
| *Irian’s light* | Clr 3 | “Ranged touch attack deals 2d8 damage, +1 ray/four levels (max 3).” | *Races of Eberron* |
| *life bolt* | Sor 2, Wiz 2 | “1 ray/2 levels draws 1 hp from you to deal 1d12 damage to undead.” No healing. | *Spell Compendium** |
| *life’s grace* | Clr 5 | “Grants immunity to many undead attacks and protection against incorporeal attacks.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *manifest life* | Clr 5, blackguard 4 | “Draw positive energy from a living creature, causing damage and granting you further options.” | *The Forge of War* |
| *panacea* | Clr 4, Dru 5 | “Removes most afflictions.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *positive energy aura* | Clr 4 | “10-ft. radius surrounding you heals 1 hp/3 levels for 1 round/level.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *protection from negative energy* | Clr 2 | “Ignore 10 points of negative energy damage per attack.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *rejuvenating light* | Clr 7 | “Touched object sheds light; undead nearby take 1d6/round positive energy damage while living creatures gain fast healing 1.” | *Complete Champion* |
| *righteous fury* | Pal 3 | “Gain temporary hp, +4 to Strength.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *righteous might* | Clr 5, Nentyar hunter 5, runescarred berserker 4, Celestia 5, Competition 5, Hatred 5, Mysticism 5, Strength 5, Wrath 5 | “Your size increases, and you gain combat bonuses.” No healing or damage. | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *sacred item* | Clr 4, Pal 4 | “Target object deals 1d4/caster level (max. 10d4) points of positive energy damage to undead, evil outsider, or evil shapechanger that touches it; undead must also save or flee for 1d4 minutes.” | *Complete Champion* |
| *seed of life* | Clr 4, Dru 5, Pal 4 | “Subject gains fast healing 2 and can invoke a burst of healing.” Living creature only. | *Complete Champion* |
| *soul of light* | Clr 3, Pal 2 | “Healing spells cast by or on you have greater effect.” | *Dragon Magic* |
| *spark of life* | Clr 3, Dru 4 | “Undead creature loses most immunities.” No healing or damage. | *Spell Compendium* |
| *stabilize* | Clr 2, Pal 2 | “Cures 1 point of damage to all creatures in area.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *synostodweomer* (aka *Symbul’s synostodweomer*) | Sor 7, Wiz 7 | “Channel a spell into positive energy to cure 1d6/spell level.” RAW, no damage, and actually heals the undead with positive energy, though this is probably an error. | *Spell Compendium** |
| *undeath’s eternal foe* | Clr 9 | “Subjects receive negative energy protection and immunity to most undead special attacks.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *undying aura* | Clr 5 | “Subject gains immunity to death effects, energy drain, and negative energy; can harm one undead or heal one deathless.” | *Magic of Eberron* |

* Appears in multiple sources; latest printing listed.

#### Negative Energy

| Spell | Level | Description | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| *animate dead* | Clr 3, Sha 4, Sor 4, Wiz 4, adept 3, blighter 4, death delver 3, death master 2, dread necromancer 4, Death 3, Undeath 3 | “Creates undead skeletons and zombies.” No healing or damage. | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *animate dread warrior* | Sor 6, Wiz 6 | (No official short description.) Animate a humanoid with all the skills it had in life. No healing or damage. | *Unapproachable East* |
| *animate legion* | Clr 4, Sor 5, Wiz 5 | “Creates skeletons or zombies.” No healing or damage. | *Heroes of Battle* |
| *black sand* | Clr 3, Sand 2 | “Creates a 20-ft.-radius area of black sand.” No direct damage or healing. | *Sandstorm* |
| *blackwater taint* | Sor 6, Wiz 6, Blackwater 6 | “*Desecrate* water, deal 1d6/2 levels negative energy damage, bestow a negative level.” | *Stormwrack* |
| *bleakness* | Clr 4, Sor 4, Wiz 4 | “1d6 damage/round to living creatures, grants undead turn resistance and fast healing.” | *Player’s Handbook II* |
| *blood snow* | Clr 2, Dru 2, Sor 3, Wiz 3, disciple of Thrym 2 | “Area of fallen snow drains 1d2 Con/round and causes nausea.” No healing. | *Frostburn* |
| *channeled lifetheft* | Sor 5, Wiz 5 | “Fatigue, exhaust, and deal damage to target, depending on casting time.” Targets living creature only, heals caster undead or alive. | *Complete Mage* |
| *chill touch* | Dsk 1, Sha 1, Sor 1, Wiz 1, blighter 2, death master 1, dread necromancer 1, Telflammar shadowlord 1, warmage 1, Cold 1 | “One touch/level deals 1d6 damage and possibly 1 Str damage.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *circlet of enervation* | Sor 5, Wiz 5 | “Subject takes damage and gains one negative level.” | *Shining South* |
| *create greater undead* | Clr 8, Sha 8, Sor 8, Wiz 8, death master 8, dread necromancer 8, Death 8, Undeath 8 | “Create shadows, wraiths, spectres, or devourers.” No healing or damage. | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *create undead* | Clr 6, Sha 6, Sor 6, Wiz 6, blighter 5, death master 5, dread necromancer 6, Evil 6, Undeath 6 | “Creates ghouls, ghasts, mummies, or mohrgs.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *curse water* | Clr 1, blighter 1, death master 1 | “Makes unholy water.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *dark tide* | Blackwater 7 | “Infuse water over a large area with negative energy, causing weakness and 1d6 damage/hour.” | *Stormwrack* |
| *death dragon* | Clr 7 | “Gain +4 natural armor, +4 deflection, and natural attacks.” No direct damage or healing, but gives at-will *inflict critical wounds* for the duration. | *Spell Compendium* |
| *defile ice and snow* | Clr 3 | “Grants undead a +4 profane bonus against turning and cold creatures SR 15 against fire spells.” No healing or damage. | *Frostburn* |
| *desecrate* | Clr 2, Divine Brd 2, knight of the chalice 2, Celestial 2 | “Fills an area with negative energy, making undead stronger.” No healing or damage. | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *desecrate battlefield* | Clr 6 | “Fills large area with negative energy, making undead stronger.” No healing or damage. | *Heroes of Battle* |
| *devastate undead* | Sor 8, Wiz 8 | (No official short description.) Pull negative energy out of undead, harming you if you’re living or healing you if you’re undead. | *Lords of Darkness* |
| *door of decay* | Clr 5 | “Move instantly from one willing or controlled undead to another.” Taps the Negative Energy Plane, which might not necessarily mean using negative energy. | *Complete Champion* |
| *dread blast* | Initiate of Cyric 4 | “Fires a ray of negative energy that deals 4d8 damage +1/level (max +20) and dazes target for 1 round.” | *Player’s Guide to Faerûn** |
| *energy ebb* | Clr 7, Sor 7, Wiz 7 | “Give subject one negative level/round for 1/round/level.” Cannot target undead (it allows a Fort save and does not target objects). | *Spell Compendium** |
| *enervating breath* | Sor 9, Wiz 9 | “Your breath weapon also bestows 2d4 negative levels.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *enervation* | Sha 4, Sor 4, Wiz 4, death delver 4, death master 4, dread necromancer 4, Thayan slaver 4, Hunger 4, Suffering 4 | “Subject gains 1d4 negative levels.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *ghoul touch* | Dsk 2, Sha 2, Sor 2, Wiz 2, death master 2, dread necromancer 2 | “Paralyzes one subject, which exudes stench that makes those nearby sickened.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *glyph of turning* | Clr 3 | “As *glyph of warding*, except channeled positive or negative energy.” Stores turning or rebuking undead. | *Ghostwalk* |
| *harm* | Clr 6 | “Deals 10 points/level damage to target.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *healing sting* | Dru 2 | “Touch deals 1d12 damage +1/level; caster gains damage as hp.” Targets living creature only. | *Spell Compendium* |
| *incorporeal enhancement* | Sor 3, Wiz 3 | “Grant bonuses to incorporeal undead.” Targets undead only. | *Spell Compendium* |
| *inflict critical wounds* | Clr 4, blighter 4, death master 4, dread necromancer 4, Destruction 4 | “Touch deals 4d8 damage +1/level (max +20).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict critical wounds, mass* | Clr 8, death master 8, dread necromancer 8 | “Touch deals 4d8 damage +1/level (max +40) for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict light wounds* | Clr 1, blighter 1, death master 1, dread necromancer 1, Destruction 1 | “Touch deals 1d8 damage +1/level (max +5).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict light wounds, mass* | Clr 5, death master 5, dread necromancer 5, Destruction 5 | “Touch deals 1d8 damage +1/level (max +25) for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict minor wounds* | Clr 0, blighter 0, death master 0 | “Touch deals 1 point of damage.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict moderate wounds* | Clr 2, blighter 2, death master 2, dread necromancer 2 | “Touch deals 2d8 damage +1/level (max +10).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict moderate wounds, mass* | Clr 6, death master 6, dread necromancer 6 | “Touch deals 2d8 damage +1/level for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict serious wounds* | Clr 3, blighter 3, death master 3, dread necromancer 3 | “Touch deals 3d8 damage +1/level (max +15).” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *inflict serious wounds, mass* | Clr 7, death master 7, dread necromancer 7 | “Touch deals 3d8 damage +1/level for many creatures.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *junglerazer* | Dru 3, Sor 3, Wiz 3 | “Fey, vermin, plants, and animals take 1d10 damage/level.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *Kyristan’s malevolent tentacles* | Sor 6, Wiz 6 | “Like *Evard’s black tentacles*, but grappled creatures gain negative levels.” | *Shining South* |
| *leech undeath* | Clr 7, Sor 8, Wiz 8 | “Harm undead to gain temporary hit points.” | *Magic of Eberron* |
| *life ward* | Clr 4 | “Grants immunity to healing spells and positive energy effects.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *manifest death* | Clr 5, blackguard 4 | “Draw negative energy from an undead, causing damage and granting you further options.” | *The Forge of War* |
| *mortal wound* | Clr 4 (Bhaal, Cyric) | (No official short description.) Ray deals 3d8 +1/level (max 20) negative energy damage (undead: healing) to target. | *Lords of Darkness* |
| *necrotic curse* | Clr 7, Sor 7, Wiz 7 | “*Cure* spells in area deal damage, living beings don’t heal with rest.” | *Complete Mage* |
| *necrotic skull bomb* | Clr 5, Sor 5, Wiz 5 | “Exploding skull releases negative energy; targets each gain 1d4 negative levels.” | *Champions of Ruin* |
| *negative energy aura* | Clr 4 | “10-ft. radius surrounding you deals 2 points of damage/round.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *negative energy burst* | Sor 3, Wiz 3 | “1d8+1/level (max +10) negative energy damage, 20-foot radius.” | *Tome and Blood* |
| *negative energy ray* | Sor 1, Wiz 1 | “Ranged touch, 1d6 negative energy damage; +1d6/two levels above first (max 5d6).” |  |
| *negative energy wave* | Sor 4, Wiz 4 | “Surge of negative energy rebukes or bolsters 1d6 HD/level (max 15d6) worth of undead.” | *Enemies and Allies** |
| *plague of undead* | Clr 9, Sor 9, Wiz 9 | “Animates horde of undead.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *positive energy protection* | Clr 3 | (No official short description.) Subject can make caster level checks to negate positive energy effects. | *Manual of the Planes* |
| *profane item* | Clr 4, blackguard 4 | “Target object deals 1d4/caster level (max. 10d4) points of negative energy damage to the next animal, plant, good outsider, or good shapechanger that touches it; animal or plant must also save or fl ee for 1d4 minutes.” | *Complete Champion* |
| *protection from positive energy* | Clr 2 | “Ignore 10 points of positive energy damage per attack.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *ravenous darkness* | Clr 7 | “Touched object sheds darkness; living creatures nearby take 1d6/round negative energy damage while undead gain fast healing 1.” | *Complete Champion* |
| *ray of entropy* | Sor 6, Wiz 6 | “Subject takes −4 Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution.” Targets living creatures only. | *Spell Compendium* |
| *reaving aura* | Asn 1, Clr 1, Hex 1, Sor 1, Wiz 1 | “Creatures below 0 hit points within 10 feet of you take 1 point of damage.” Targets living creatures only. | *Complete Mage* |
| *rebuking breath* | Sor 4, Wiz 4 | “Your breath weapon rebukes undead.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *rejuvenative corpse* | Clr 3 | “Negative energy fills corpse, feeding undead healed.” No damage. | *Spell Compendium* |
| *retributive enervation* | Sor 7, Wiz 7 | “Any living creature that strikes you in melee gains a negative level.” | *Complete Mage* |
| *revive undead* | Sor 6, Wiz 6, Deathbound 5 | “Restores undeath to undead that was destroyed up to 1 day/level ago.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *seed of undeath* | Clr 4, Sor 4, Wiz 4 | “Subject that dies before spell expires rises as a zombie under your command.” | *Complete Mage* |
| *shroud of undeath* | Clr 2, Sor 2, Wiz 2 | “Negative energy shroud makes undead perceive you as undead.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *skeletal guard* | Sor 8, Wiz 8 | “Create one skeleton/level with turn resistance.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *slashing darkness* | Clr 3 | “Ray deals 1d8/2 levels damage or heals undead the same amount.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *soul of shadow* | Clr 3, blackguard 2 | “*Inflict wounds* spells cast by or on you have greater effect.” | *Dragon Magic* |
| *spectral touch* | Sor 6, Wiz 6 | “Your touch bestows one negative level/round.” | *Spell Compendium** |
| *summon undead I* | Sor 1, Wiz 1 | “Summons undead to fight for you.” | _Spell Compendium* |
| *summon undead II* | Sor 2, Wiz 2 | “Summons undead to fight for you.” | _Spell Compendium* |
| *summon undead III* | Sor 3, Wiz 3 | “Summons undead to fight for you.” | _Spell Compendium* |
| *summon undead IV* | Sor 4, Wiz 4 | “Summons undead to fight for you.” | _Spell Compendium* |
| *summon undead V* | Sor 5, Wiz 5 | “Summons undead to fight for you.” | _Spell Compendium* |
| *sword of darkness* | Sor 7, Wiz 7 | “Blade of negative energy bestows one or more negative levels.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *touch of fatigue* | Dsk 0, Sha 0, Sor 0, Wiz 0, adept 0, blighter 0, death master 0, Sloth 1 | “Touch attack fatigues target.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *touch of the graveborn* | Sor 8, Wiz 8 | “Melee touch attack deals 10d6 damage or controls undead creature.” | *Spell Compendium* |
| *touch of Vecna* | Sor 5, Wiz 5 | “Deal negative energy damage and paralysis with your touch.” Targets living creatures only. | *Complete Mage* |
| *undead mask* | Clr 7 | “Subject’s type changes to undead.” No direct healing or damage. | *Savage Species* |
| *undeath after death* | Clr 7 | “−2 to Constitution, in exchange for gaining the crypt spawn template at death.” Targets living creatures only. | *Magic of Faerûn* |
| *waves of exhaustion* | Sha 7, Sor 7, Wiz 7, blighter 8, death master 7, dread necromancer 6, Hades 8, Sloth 8 | “Several targets become exhausted.” | *Player’s Handbook* |
| *waves of fatigue* | Dsk 5, Sha 5, Sor 5, Wiz 5, blighter 5, death master 5, dread necromancer 5, Hades 6, Sloth 6 | “Several targets become fatigued.” | *Player’s Handbook* |

* Appears in multiple sources; latest printing listed.

Negative energy is a lot harder, because it’s not necessarily clear what does or doesn’t use it. It’s possible that many if not most necromancy spells use it, for example. I have listed only those that explicitly state they use it, or that behave differently on living vs. undead creatures, or that contrast the effect with positive energy, or that create undead. And I have probably missed a few of those.

Answer (score -1):

**Google is often helpful**; [this query](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awww.d20srd.org%2Fsrd%2Fspells%20%22positive%22) returned what seemed a good starting point of (SRD) positive spells. Just swap out "positive" for "negative", and you'll get those as well.

Non-SRD material is, of course, not something that should be available on the web.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I did put down positive spell but I was not getting the same list you managed to get... Did you use some specific search setting?

Comment: @Digius I aimed Google at the d20srd site and the subdirectory srd/spells, then used "positive" inside quotation marks to force Google to respect that keyword. No settings, but pretty restrictive and explicit filters. You're welcome!